# How can I fix this layout built with twitter bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a sample form layout with twitter bootstrap. The form lists the fields in horizontal order and in between the fields I have a link. When this link is clicked I would like to show some bullet points on the right of the fields. However these bullet points are not lining up well with the form on the left.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/3643/

**Questions**

- How can I have the bullets on the right side be inside the same grey box that the form is in. These bullets server as additional information for the form and having them in separate grey box looks weird.
- The space between field `One` and `Two` is a lot just because I added a link. How can I make the space consistent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nest the bullets on the right hand side inside your form box container element, and the extra space is being added to the `<p>` element - add a class to identify it and reduce it in the CSS.

Comment: i.e. add `<ul class="something">
              <li class="one">one</li>
              <li class="two">two</li>
           </ul>` to be within the nested html that begins `<div class="span7">
            <form class="form-horizontal well ">`

Comment: hmm I tried that but that makes the bullets show up at the bottom of the form like this: http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/3644/

Comment: I would put it inside `<div>`, and take the `well` class off the form element and add it to the `<div>` like so: `<div class="span7 well">`

Comment: This works - `.well` is on the `div` now as well instead of the `form`. http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/3646/

Comment: no...that shows up the bullet at the center and after all the fields. I want the bullets to show on the right, starting parallel to the first field.

Comment: somehow the form tag should be fluid so something can be added along the right of it